# Oauth2client error when trying Apache Beams example code

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to run the Apache Beam Python examples (for example https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/game/user_score.py ). When I run the script I get

```
(py27) XXX-MBP:my_path$ python user_score.py --output /my_path/user_score_output
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
INFO:root:Missing pipeline option (runner). Executing pipeline using the default runner: DirectRunner.
/my_path_2/miniconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py:121: DeprecationWarning: object() takes no parameters
  super(GcsIO, cls).__new__(cls, storage_client))
INFO:root:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:root:Finished the size estimation of the input at 1 files. Estimation took 0.453105211258 seconds
/my_path_2/miniconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py:135: UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: Any.
  warnings.warn('Using fallback coder for typehint: %r.' % typehint)
/my_path_2/miniconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py:135: UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: <type 'NoneType'>.
  warnings.warn('Using fallback coder for typehint: %r.' % typehint)
INFO:root:Running pipeline with DirectRunner.
INFO:root:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:root:Finished the size estimation of the input at 2 files. Estimation took 0.477814912796 seconds
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
```

The problem seems to be with Oauth2client and getting an access token. I googled a bit and people are talking about setting consent='prompt' but it is in the domain of asking users for consent. Here I am just downloading a dataset. Is it access to my Google Cloud service that might be struggling? Other programs can write programs to Google Cloud Storage. I am looking at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 but I don't really understand what I am supposed to be doing ...

Comment: did you figure this out?